# respondsToSelector for super class invocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, polymorphism, objective-c-runtime

I have the following method:

```
- (void) someMethod
{
    if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)])
    {
        [super performSelector:@selector(someMethod)
                    withObject:nil];
    }
}
```

someMethod **does not** exist on superclass. as i understand, if there is no such method, runtime will ask the next responder in chain for such method till the NSObject class. And i was sure, that if statement will return NO.

Statement return YES. After that it performs selector without crash. As result - infinite recursion.

so, i have two questions:

1. Why `[super respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)]` returns YES ?
2. Why  `[super performSelector:@selector(someMethod) withObject:nil]`  does not crash with error 'does not responds to selector' ?

I think i've missed something essential.
Please, help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you missed something essential as you suggest. From the documentation for `respondsToSelector:`

> You cannot test whether an object inherits a method from its superclass by sending `respondsToSelector:` to the object using the `super` keyword. This method will still be testing the object as a whole, not just the superclass’s implementation. Therefore, sending `respondsToSelector:` to `super` is equivalent to sending it to `self`. Instead, you must invoke the `NSObject` class method `instancesRespondToSelector:` directly on the object’s superclass, as illustrated in the following code fragment.

```
if( [MySuperclass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(aMethod)] )
{
   // invoke the inherited method
   [super aMethod];
}
```

HTH